# Angularjs create dynamic copy of global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a weather app with jQuery and Angular.  Simply put, here's my code:

```
(function() {
    forecast = {};
    (function($) {
        forecast.head = "date";
    }(jQuery)();
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    var forecastController = app.controller("forecastController", function() {
        this.data = forecast;
    });
}());
```

and my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <table ng-controller="forecastController as forecast">
        <thead ng-repeat="item in forecast.data.head">
            <th>{{item}}</th>
        </thead>
        ...
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, it is not outputting anything.  The jQuery uses an ajax call to get the weather, which is async.  If I don't make it async, everything works well.  However, I want it to be async.

Please help!

Comment: I recommend you to make the async ajax call from within angular, so you can have more control over it. Lookup $http and promises for that.

Comment: @Fedaykin Unfortunately the plugin is written in jQuery.  Thanks anyway.  I think I have to implement some $scope.$watch thing but have no idea how to do it.  If I turn async off on the ajax call, it works.

Comment: You could create a directive to wrap the jquery part and use it

Comment: Also you dont have to do `var forecast = ..` it overwites the actual variable

Comment: @PSL I am a beginner, what do you mean by directive? Could you please provide me a link?

Comment: @Nathan WIthout a directive this is how it will be http://jsbin.com/sowubore/1/ and here is the [official doc for directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) Here is the code. http://jsbin.com/sowubore/1/edit